# Is the ASP.NET session data changed?

Tags: asp.net, session

```
List<Foo> fooList = Session["foo"] as List<Foo>;
fooList.Add(bar);
```

Does the call to Add() change the data that's in the session?  Put another way: when I next pull "foo" from the Session, will the list contain `bar`?

Comment: I guess I'm asking whether the Session returns by val or ref?

Comment: Session is holding what is effectively a pointer to the List<>.  So when you retrieve it and mess with the List<> you are messing with the same List<> that is stored in Session.  @Darin gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the session will be changed as a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a reference type. All that this `fooList` variable represents is a pointer to the real object and all that `Session["foo"]` represents is also a pointer to the same object. So changing `fooList` will affect the real object that the session is also pointing to. The behavior will be different if you store value types in session.